# Org Id when managed package is installed

Tags: managed-package

Is it possible to get org Id when i install a manage package to any salesforce org. i.e. I have a managed package when it get installed in a org I want to get the org id and send it to an another org, where it get saved. Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the org id in post install script and post it to your ORG.

here is how to get org ID from .

```
Id OrgId = context.organizationId()
```

Here is how you can use InstallHandler Interface to automatically run your code which post the org id.

```
global class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        Id OrgId = context.organizationId();    
        //call future method and pass OrgId
        //From future method call api and pass the orgID
    }
}
```

Ref : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [LMA (Licence Management App)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_package_details.htm), then a `sfLma__License__c` object will be added to the LMA Org when the managed package is installed. That object has a `sfLma__Subscriber_Org_ID__c` field that contains the org ID you are interested in. You can use normal salesforce techniques in the LMA org to respond to that insert and perform what ever additional processing you want.

Comment: I would really advise this. While @AtulRajguru9 's solution may work, why reinvent the wheel? the LMA gives you quite a few features out-of-the-box.

Comment: Can you plz provide some doc related to this 'sfLma__License__c' object not able to find anything here.

Comment: @Anu Install the LMA and you can see the object definitions.